# How to this expected output in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
EventId   Status
-----------------
 1         A
 2         B
 1         B
 2         B
 3         A
 3         B
 4         B
```

Output

```
EventId     Status
-------------------    
    2         B
    4         B
```

How to get this output?

I need only those event id whose status only 'B' if any status comes as 'A' it also discard that Event Id.... I try query as distinct and row number ...but I'm not getting output...

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select eventid, max(status)
from t
group by eventid
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'B';
```

There are many other ways.  For instance:

```
select distinct eventid, status
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.eventid = t.eventid and t2.status <> 'B');
```

Or, the confusing:

```
select eventId, status
from t
where status = 'B'
except
select eventId, 'B'
from t
where status <> 'B';
```